# Angular4 directive - Set input value according to previous value

Tags: angular

I need to write angular4 directive which checks a condition on input:
If the input string is 'false' => leave the previous written value. Else => set the new given value.

Here is my shot:

```
 import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';
    import {NgModel} from "@angular/forms";

    @Directive({ selector: '[ngModel][prevVal]'})
    export class PrevValDirective {

      constructor(private el: ElementRef,private model:NgModel) {
      }

      @HostListener('ngModelChange',['$event'])
      onModelChange(event){

        if(event != 'false') {
          this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(event);
          return true;
        }

        this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(this.model.value);
        return false;
      }
    }
```

But it seems like onModelChange is catched after the model already changed.

Can someone assist ? How can I undo change if the user enters 'false' (or I can I get the previous value before 'false' was entered)?

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: shouldn't it be event.value ?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/yftpJ4A1HwrKkpfcSIT7?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui can you write it down as an answer so I would accept it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to override `onChange` method for `ControlValueAccessor`:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[ngModel][prevVal]'})
export class PrevValDirective {
  constructor(private valueAccessor: DefaultValueAccessor, private model: NgModel) {
    valueAccessor.registerOnChange = (fn: (val: any) => void) => {
      valueAccessor.onChange = (val) => {
        if(val === 'false') {
          model.control.setValue(model.value);
          return;
        }
        return fn(val);
      };
    }
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/yftpJ4A1HwrKkpfcSIT7?p=preview)**

Here is the picture that describes how angular form control works.

[image]

I just made some hook that prevents calling `onChange` (3-4)

Comment: Hi, I see now that there is a slight problem. I want the input to remove the false value and instead put the previous value.

Comment: If i type `tru` then `true`. what should happen in this case?

Comment: If you type "fals" and then "false" then input should have "fals".
In addition: if there was "hello world" and you pasted "false" input should have "hello world"

Comment: Updated plunker

Comment: thanks. Can you explain what is the difference between registerOnChange and onChange ?

Comment: `registerOnChange` is like a bridge between view and model https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.1.3/packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts#L42. It is used to register function that will be called when `input` value is changed

Comment: Let me create picture

Comment: ok so if registerOnChange is a bridge, why do I need the onChange registration?

Comment: `onChange` functon is responsible for `input` event callback. We have to define it. Without it typing in `input` control won't change model

Comment: i'm trying to implement your solution by implementing "ControlValueAccessor" interface. Can you take a look on this plunker and see why it won't work ?
https://plnkr.co/edit/awonRnwOIGQMMs6XEx75?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the previous value:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[ngModel][prevVal]'})
export class PrevValDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef,private model:NgModel) {
  }

  private previousValue: any;

  @HostListener('ngModelChange',['$event'])
  onModelChange(event){

    if (event != 'false') {
      this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(event);
      return true;
    }

    this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(this.previousValue);

    this.previousValue = event.value;

    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I know I can use an additional var. isn't any other way to "cancel" the new val?

Comment: @ohadinho I don't think so.